# C# inheritance pass down template values

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

i get a kind of tree inheritance relation. each upper node could be considered as template values. and the lower nodes have exact same values and some new columns( kind of values).

I want to know is there are easy way to pass down these values form upper nodes to lower nodes.

my code like:

```
    public class rootData
    {
        public long sID;
        public string sName;
        public string title;
        public string country;

       <many....many...columns>

    };

    public class sub1 : rootData
    {
        public void load(rootData template)
        {
            this.sID= template.sID;
            this.sName= template.sName;
            this.title= template.title;
            this.country= template.country;

            <many....many...asigns>
        }
        public int sNumberA;
        public int sNumberB;
    };
```

i want to know: is there any way to write like

`this.everything=template.everything`

to replace that many many lines of asigns :

```
            this.sID= template.sID;
            this.sName= template.sName;
            this.title= template.title;
            this.country= template.country;

            <many....many...asigns>
```

Comment: What about changing the relationship from "is-a" to "has-a"?

Comment: yes  i just want  "has-a" then how?

Comment: I would highly highly recommend converting those fields to properties.

Comment: In this example, if I change the template's values, should it change the derived sub1 values?

Comment: actually ... upper values never change... never think about that

Answer (score 0):

Make `rootData` a field in `sub1`, and add a parameter to the constructor with which to populate this field.  If the fields in `rootData` are largely "dumb" labels, I'd make it a `struct`, to illustrate that it's just a simple collection of data with little or no logic on top.

As Erik pointed out, properties would probably be superior.  Note that you could expose the individual fields in `rootData` as props, and avoid broadcasting to other classes the details of your class (namely, that it has a `rootData` field).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to whether you can do it is whether you want inheritance or composition.  Do you want the `sub1` to BE a `rootData`?  If so, you're going to need to copy the values.  Do you want the `sub1` to CONTAIN a `rootData`?  If so, you can have the `sub1` hold the values of the `rootData` that you pass in.  Of course, if you do that, you can't have it be a separate `rootData` without copying the values anyway.

My short answer is: create a function to copy the values.  You only have to do it once.